# AWS JS S3: What is the type of 'stream' in ManagedUpload?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Looking at 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html#constructor-property

```
var upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
  params: {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key', Body: stream}
});
```

Body is suppose to be a `stream`. How can I create a `stream` from local file if I want to use this `ManagedUpload` in a browser?

And is that `stream` different than `streamObject` in `uploadPart`

```
Body: new Buffer('...') || 'STRING_VALUE' || streamObject,
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#uploadPart-property

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Their documentation is horrendous. They have no good examples. You could try a `FileReader` object and the `readAsArrayBuffer` method. Something like:

```
    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = (function(file) {
    return function(e) {
        var upload;
        if (e.eventPhase == 2) {
            upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
                params: {Bucket: 'annuals-original', Key: 'name', Body: e.currentTarget.result}
            }).send(function(err, data) {
                console.log(err, data);
            });
         };
    })(f);

    // Read in the image file 
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
```

You could attach an eventHandler to an input tag.

```
<input type="file" id="input" multiple onchange="handleFile(this.files)">
```

Then pass the file to the handler.

```
inputElement.addEventListener("change", handleFile, false);
```